# Different ways for starting Java app from Windows 10 Power Shell are not equal

Tags: java, powershell

I want to start a Java app (namely a jar file) from Windows 10 Power Shell.

I have two scripts:

```
Start-Process `
-FilePath ".\jdk-17.0.7+7\bin\java.exe" `
-ArgumentList "-classpath myfile.jar MainApplication"
```

and

```
Start-Process `
-FilePath ".\jdk-17.0.7+7\bin\java.exe" `
-ArgumentList "-jar myfile.jar"
```

in MAINFEST.MF I have:

```
Main-class: MainApplication
```

So, the first script starts but throws an exception somewhere in the code.

```
2023-07-07 18:15:02.397 SEVERE: java.lang.IllegalStateException: HTTP factory has not been set
java.lang.IllegalStateException: HTTP factory has not been set
```

And the question here is why the second script starts the application without such an exception.
Yes, there are some warnings, but not like this, and the Java application is started.

And this is happening with Java 17 only.
So the next script (using Java 11) doesn't throw mentioned exception either.

```
Start-Process `
-FilePath ".\jdk-11.0.19+7\bin\java.exe" `
-ArgumentList "-classpath myfile.jar MainApplication"
```

I expected both starting methods to be equal but in fact, they differ somewhere. Where?

Comment: *java.lang.IllegalStateException: HTTP factory has not been set* we'd probably need to see the full stack trace to evaluate that

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/pl71/java-start/blob/main/stack-trace) is the output. This is when trying to start [JOSM](https://github.com/JOSM/josm) from PowerShell using 1st script.

Comment: Well you're not trying to start JOSM are you - you're trying to start your own jar. And that jar is missing the JOSM jar(s) from its classpath, so you will need to add it/them

Comment: @g00se No, I've tried to start exactly JOSM from [here](https://github.com/Gubaer/josm-scripting-plugin/tree/97-esmodules-on-win10-2/testing/windows). But noticed a difference in starting approaches (-cp vs -jar). So it was a little weird to me.

Comment: Ok. The broad issue of `-cp` versus `-jar` has been explained in the answer. I'm not sure where you are now but if things are still not working I suggest you turn `Start-Process` into `Write-File` temporarily and post the contents of the file in your question formatted as code

Answer (score 1):

When using `-jar`, the class-path used to start the app is defined as follows:

- Take the jar and include it - that part is obvious.
- Read the jar manifest's `Class-Path` entry. (It's separated by spaces). Resolve each item relative to the folder that contains the jar you are running, and add them all to the classpath.

In contrast, using `-cp`, you get *that* as class-path.

The difference, therefore, is the manifest `Class-Path` entry, which is used when using `-jar` (and in fact, is the only thing being used; `-jar` and `-cp` cannot be used together), and not used at all when using the `-cp` flag (the manifest is ignored when you do that).

Check the manifest for `Class-Path` entries.

Comment: There are no `Class-Path` entries in the manifest file. CLASSPATH environmental variable is not set in the system either (if relevant at all).